# Can I use Boost program_options to get multiple arbitrary-key-value pairs?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, key-value, boost-program-options

I'm writing a program  using Boost's program_options library. Now, I want to allow it to extend with arbitrary code, which the configuration parser is not aware of - but which would still get some specific options passed to it.

My idea was to somehow pass it a key-value map, possibly even a program_options::variable_map . The thing is, program_options needs to know which options to expect in advance, I can't directly a map with the keys I like.

So, I was thinking maybe I could get program_options to accept arbitrary key-value pairs with string keys (if necessary, string values), put those in some map from string to either string or std::experimental::any, and pass that onwards.

To be more concrete, I'll give an example (although it doesn't have to be quite like this exactly). I would write:

```
$ magic_app --key1 val1 --key2 val2 --key3 val3 positional1 positional2
```

and suppose program_options knows about `key2` but not about `key1` or `key3`. Then it will...

- parse `key2`,
- create a map containins two keys, `key1` and `key3`, with values `val1` and `val2` respectively (say string values), and
- parse the positional arguments `positional1` and `positional2`.

So that the app can pass on the map (perhaps after some transformation) to another component with its own argument processor.

Is this doable? Is there a simpler/better alternative I could use with `boost::program_options`?

**Notes:**

- Somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35133523/c-boost-program-options-multiple-lists-of-arguments), which could serve as a crude implementation with some post-parsing - keys will be odd elements in the list, values will be the even elements.
- The user must be able to specify the options unknown to `program_options` just like all other options.

Comment: Can you provide an example (code or pseudo-code) of what you want to do?

Comment: The main point of Boost.ProgramOptions is to be able for it detect if the user entered the wrong keys. You basically just want a program option *lexer*, which breaks the options down into tokens that you will process and decide which are valid.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a string option that can be given multiple times...

```
( 
  "kvp",
  boost::program_options::value< std::vector< std::string > >(),
  "key-value pair"
)
```

...and then *give* that option as often as you like:

```
--kvp key1:val1 --kvp key2:val2
```

At that point, you have your key-value pairs as strings in a vector, which should be easy enough to parse.

```
if ( vm.count( "kvp" ) )
{
    std::vector< std::string > kvps = vm["kvp"].as< std::vector< std::string > >();

    for ( auto & kvp : kvps )
    {
        // kvp is one key-value pair
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of options to choose from:

```
theProgram.exe --unknown_key_values "key1:value1 key2:value2 ..."
```

Tokenize on blanks and then on ":" to get your key value pairs.

```
theProgram.exe --unknown_key_values "--key1 value1 --key2 value2 ..."
```

and pass the string into a second program_options parser that knows the keys expected

```
theProgram.exe --key key1 --value value1 --key key2 --value value2 ...
```

which will give you two string vectors with each key and its value in corresponding indices.

```
theProgram.exe --key1 value1 --key2 value2 ...
```

If key1 etc are unknown you will get an exception from the parser which you can catch and handle the raw string.  If you hace a mixture of known and unknown keys, you will have to handle each unknown key ( storing it and stripping it out of the command line ) then loop around to process the remaining keys until you do not get an exception

Comment: Ah, no. It's important that the user specify these options just as if they were regular program options. S/he can also specify them in a config file, which `program_options` supports, and I certainly do not want the config file to look like that.